# c3js - Change point color on focus

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Is it possible to change the color of a point (scatter plot) in c3.js?

my code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    ...
    point: {
        r: function(d) {
            return Math.random() * 3;
        },
        focus: {
            expand: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably need to do it by delving down into the D3 that underpins it.

Here's a fiddle/example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/9/

The `onmouseover: function(d)` gives you the data point index (`d.index`), and you can use that to find the nth circle on the svg, and then change the color (fill). Use the `onmouseout` to similarly reset the color to what it was previously.